# R Programming: Where is the value of the matrix scored?

Tags: r, matrix, caching

I have a function which returns a list of 3 sub functions as follows:

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
inversedMatrix <- NULL
get <- function() x
setMatrix <- function(matrix) inversedMatrix <<- matrix
getMatrix <- function() inversedMatrix
list(get = get,
   setMatrix = setMatrix,
   getMatrix = getMatrix)
}
```

When I create an object by passing the `matrix(1:4, 2, 2)` to this function using `matrixcal <- makeCacheMatrix(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))` the value of the `matrix(1:4, 2, 2)` gets stored somewhere. I want to understand where this value is being stored as I do not see it in R studio in the Global environment. Clearly it is being stored somewhere as I can access it later using `matrixcal$get()`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your function

```
foo <- makeCacheMatrix(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))
```

Then look at the object

```
foo
# $get
# function() x
# <environment: 0x0000021849b5da78>

# $setMatrix
# function(matrix) inversedMatrix <<- matrix
# <environment: 0x0000021849b5da78>

# $getMatrix
# function() inversedMatrix
# <environment: 0x0000021849b5da78>
```

You'll see that each of the functions has an associated environment (your exact numbers/digits will be different each time you run the function). Your function has created a closure environment to store the variables and functions created.

You can access that environment via

```
environment(foo$get)
```

which just gives you the environment object. You can list the contents of that environment with

```
ls.str(environment(foo$get))
# get : function ()  
# getMatrix : function ()  
# inversedMatrix :  NULL
# setMatrix : function (matrix)  
# x :  int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
```

And there you'll see the original matrix stored in the `x` value of that environment.